# std vector erase and push_back

Tags: addition, stdvector, erase

I have the following cycle:

```
vector<int>   vec;
vector<int>::iterator it;
// fill the vector with some values. func() is a boolean function on ints.
// fill_vec() fills a vector of ints with some values.
for ( it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); )
{
    if ( func( *it ) )
    {
        vector<int> new_vec;
        fill_vec( new_vec );   
        it = erase(it);
        for ( int j =0 ; j < new_vec.size(); j++ )
            vec.push_back( new_vec[j] );
    }
    else
        it++;
}
```

Is this a valid loop? That is, am i erasing/adding elements inside the loop in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to find out is to compile and trace it through to check your logic - you'll learn a great deal. As it stands I don't believe it will compile, and your replacement vector elements probably aren't going where you expect. Also, check out vector::insert() for inserting a range from another container.